# How to show something only in mobile and not desktop using fxLayout for Angular Material

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material, progressive-web-apps

Here is my code:

```xml
<div fxLayout="column" fxHide.xs
  style ="background-color: #263238; color: white; border-top: none;">
  <button mat-icon-button fxHide.md>
      <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-icon-button fxHide.md>
      <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-icon-button fxHide.md>
        <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
```

The above is a container that I only want to show on a mobile but not on a browser. How should I go about coding it?

Comment: you can use Platform API - https://material.angular.io/cdk/platform/api

Comment: Hi I am not familar with Fxlayout, but I think this should work `fxHide.sm="false"` `fxHide.md="true"`

Comment: try using this line `<div fxHide fxShow.xs></div>`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan nope it still doesn't work. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: @AliWahab thanks, but it still not working though... :/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fxHide.xs you can use something like

```
fxHide.gt-sm
```

to show only on mobile

Comment: Hi.. I tried that too but same to no avail... For some reason... this only work in app.component

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/BreakPoints#custom-breakpointsts

Using the custom breakpoints as

```
custom-breakpoints.ts
```

```
import {BREAKPOINT} from '@angular/flex-layout';

const CUSTOM_BREAKPOINTS = [{
  alias: 'xs.mobilescreen',
  suffix: 'XsMobileScreen',
  mediaQuery: 'screen and (max-width: 480px)',
// Your break points for the specific screen width
  overlapping: false,
}];

export const CustomBreakPointsProvider = { 
  provide: BREAKPOINT,
  useValue: CUSTOM_BREAKPOINTS,
  multi: true
};
```

```
my-app-module.ts
import {CommonModule, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {CustomBreakPointsProvider} from './custom-breakpoints.ts';

@NgModule({
  imports : [
    CommonModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    CustomBreakPointsProvider,     // Adds breakpoints for mobile mediaQueries
  ]
})
export class MyAppModule {
}
```

Now in app module

```
import {InjectionToken, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BREAKPOINTS, DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS, FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';

export const BreakPointsProvider = { 
  provide: BREAKPOINTS,
  useValue: DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS,
  multi: true
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    FlexLayoutModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    BreakPointsProvider,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Try implementation using the above mentioned way for doing the mobile break points then use the alias to hide and show

Comment: Why are there 2 app module?

Answer (score 0):

this is not really a solution but I find the flex hide and shown only seem to work in my app.component